# Do others need to install CocoaPods to build my project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have made an app for a university project, which uses CocoaPods for dependency management (I have 2 pods included). I have to upload this project, and provide an installation guide for a reviewer. My question is: will others be able to just open the xcworkspace file as is, or do they also need to install cocoapods themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you plan to give your source code to the reviewers.

`Cocoapods` is just a way of installing and managing libraries. If all you do is zip your project folder and send it to the reviewers, they won't need to install `Cocoapods` because the needed `Pods` are already included in your project.

If you planned on giving them the code by giving them access to your repository, **they will need `Cocoapods` if your repository ignores the Pods folder** (ex: you added the Pods folder in your `.gitignore`). If your Pods are commited to the repository, they won't need it.

Comment: I have to upload the source files as they are. I guess I'm good to go then?